# Java applet not visible in Chrome

Tags: java, javascript, google-chrome

I'm running into some kind race condition in a Java applet, peculiar to Google Chrome (win xp).
I'm writing the `<applet>` tag into a popup window.

The problem is characterised by:

1. The applet **always shows fine in MS IE and Firefox**.
2. In Chrome The applet only displays about **50%** of the time.
3. When it doesn't display, the applet actually appears to be silently running perfectly from the Java console! No errors!
4. The `JApplet`'s `init()` and `start()` methods are always called.
5. `isShowing()` and `isDisplayable()` always return `true`, even when the applet does not show.
6. When it doesn't show, the `paint()` method **isn't** called.
7. When the applet doesn't show, a transparent rectangular area (of the window background colour) where the applet should have been can be noticed when the text in the window is selected. From this I take it that the applet region is correctly placed in the window.

### My code:

MyApplet.java

```
  package mypackage;
  public class MyApplet extends JApplet  {
    public void init(){
      super.init();
      getContentPane().add(new JLabel("Hello"), BorderLayout.CENTER);
      System.out.println("init ok");
    }
    public void start() {
      super.start();
      System.out.println("s parent:"+this.getParent());
      System.out.println("s disp:"+this.isDisplayable());
      System.out.println("s showing:"+this.isShowing());      
    }
    public void paint(Graphics g){
      System.out.println("painting");
      super.paint(g);
    }
  }
```

test.html

```
<HTML>
<SCRIPT language='JavaScript'>
var jarpath='./myjar.jar';
var classname='mypackage.MyApplet';
function opentest(){
  applet=window.open('', '', "height=420,width=620");
  applet.document.write(
    '<html><body>'+
    '<OBJECT classid="clsid:8AD9C840-044E-11D1-B3E9-00805F499D93"'+
       'width=600 height=400>'+
        '<param name=code value="'+classname+'">'+
        '<param name=archive value="'+jarpath+'">'+
        '<param name=type value="application/x-java-applet;version1.3">'+
        '<COMMENT>'+
          '<EMBED code="'+classname+'" archive="'+jarpath+'" ' +
                  'type="application/x-java-applet;version=1.3" ' +
                  'width=600 height=400 ' +
              '>'+
            '<NOEMBED>' +
               'unavailable'+ 
            '</NOEMBED>'+
          '</EMBED>' +
        '</COMMENT>' +
     '</OBJECT>'+
   '</body></html>' );
}
</SCRIPT>

<BODY>
  Click here to open <A onclick="opentest()">Test</A>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

### Output from console

50% of the time I click on 'Test', the new window contains the 'Hello' label. The other 50% of the time, the window is blank as described. 
The console output seems identical when the applet loads and doesn't load. It seems blameless!

```
security: property package.access value sun.,com.sun.xml.internal.ws.,com.sun.xml.internal.bind.,com.sun.imageio.
security: property package.access new value sun.,com.sun.xml.internal.ws.,com.sun.xml.internal.bind.,com.sun.imageio.,com.sun.javaws
security: property package.access value sun.,com.sun.xml.internal.ws.,com.sun.xml.internal.bind.,com.sun.imageio.,com.sun.javaws
security: property package.access new value sun.,com.sun.xml.internal.ws.,com.sun.xml.internal.bind.,com.sun.imageio.,com.sun.javaws,com.sun.deploy
security: property package.access value sun.,com.sun.xml.internal.ws.,com.sun.xml.internal.bind.,com.sun.imageio.,com.sun.javaws,com.sun.deploy
security: property package.access new value sun.,com.sun.xml.internal.ws.,com.sun.xml.internal.bind.,com.sun.imageio.,com.sun.javaws,com.sun.deploy,com.sun.jnlp
security: property package.definition value null
security: property package.definition new value com.sun.javaws
security: property package.definition value com.sun.javaws
security: property package.definition new value com.sun.javaws,com.sun.deploy
security: property package.definition value com.sun.javaws,com.sun.deploy
security: property package.definition new value com.sun.javaws,com.sun.deploy,com.sun.jnlp
security: property package.access value sun.,com.sun.xml.internal.ws.,com.sun.xml.internal.bind.,com.sun.imageio.,com.sun.javaws,com.sun.deploy,com.sun.jnlp
security: property package.access new value sun.,com.sun.xml.internal.ws.,com.sun.xml.internal.bind.,com.sun.imageio.,com.sun.javaws,com.sun.deploy,com.sun.jnlp,org.mozilla.jss
security: property package.definition value com.sun.javaws,com.sun.deploy,com.sun.jnlp
security: property package.definition new value com.sun.javaws,com.sun.deploy,com.sun.jnlp,org.mozilla.jss
basic: Added progress listener: sun.plugin.util.GrayBoxPainter$GrayBoxProgressListener@137c60d
basic: Plugin2ClassLoader.addURL parent called for file:/E:/Java/eclipse/MyApplet/myjar.jar
network: Cache entry not found [url: file:/E:/Java/eclipse/MyApplet/myjar.jar, version: null]
network: Cache entry not found [url: file:/E:/Java/eclipse/MyApplet/myjar.jar, version: null]
basic: Applet loaded.
basic: Applet resized and added to parent container
basic: PERF: AppletExecutionRunnable - applet.init() BEGIN ; jvmLaunch dt 145396 us, pluginInit dt 331540 us, TotalTime: 476936 us
init ok
basic: Applet initialized
basic: Removed progress listener: sun.plugin.util.GrayBoxPainter$GrayBoxProgressListener@137c60d
basic: Applet made visible
basic: Starting applet
basic: completed perf rollup
s parent:sun.plugin2.main.client.PluginEmbeddedFrame[frame0,0,0,600x400,invalid,layout=java.awt.BorderLayout,title=,resizable,normal]
s disp:true
s showing:true
basic: Applet started
basic: Told clients applet is started
```

### Update

Thanks to Ates, trying the following timeout makes the Applet appear correctly **100% of the time**.

```
function opentest(){
  applet=window.open('', '', "height=420,width=620");
  setTimeout(function () {
    applet.document.write( ... ); } ,
    1000 );
}
```

- As Ates mentions, we now see that our popup window doesn't like immediate `document.write`s!
- Is this correct behaviour? Am I supposed to wait for some signal before writing to a document?
- Should I be going about this a different way? Can I add some kind of listener to know when it is safe to call `document.write()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
applet = window.open('', '', "height=420,width=620");
applet.document.write(...
```

This could be where your race condition starts. You may be trying to change the document of the newly opened window without the window being properly initialized. A quick thing to try is to let the currently running JavaScript thread "breathe", by deferring the rest of the code to a dummy timeout that will run asynchronously:

```
applet = window.open('', '', "height=420,width=620");
setTimeout(function () {
    applet.document.write(...
}, 0);
```

This is not necessarily the best way to resolve this issue, but it is a quick thing to try to see if this is in fact the source of the race condition.

Comment: Ah - this is interesting! With a timeout of 0, the yield is increased to about 75% success. With a timeout of 1000ms, the popup **always** works correctly! Since this is for web deployment, I'd like to be doing things **"correctly"** where possible - any suggestions of how to track the problem down further?

Comment: I've added this info to the question. Thanks for this helpful suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

I have had some issues with ad blockers blocking my Applets from being visible on occasion. Though it working 50/50 seems odd.

Comment: Thanks, I've just tried disabling the "phishing and malware protection" - to no avail. And it's a completely clean install of Chrome + Java 1.6...